# Remove a div with its class name

Tags: javascript, android, dom

I have a URL link which I am displaying in WebView.
Now, when this page loads I need to remove certain elements/ blocks from this web page so that only a certain part is present.

I am using javascript inside onPageFinished method for this. here is how I am doing it :

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('main_nav').style.display=\"none\";");
```

this works fine, but for some divs, id is not present instead of that we have just class eg.-

```
<div class="left_rail">
```

Now, i have to remove this div, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried this -

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('main').getElementsByClassName('left_rail').style.display=\"none\";");
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements. The first of which can be obtained this way:

```
getElementsByClassName('left_rail')[0]
```

Use a loop to get rid of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

if the browser supports "document.getElementsByClassName":

```
document.getElementsByClassName("className")[0].style.display = "none";
```

or supports "document.querySelector":

```
document.querySelector(".className").style.display = "none";
```

or you are using jquery:

```
$(".className").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can just do this $(".classname").hide();